# Haskell RethinkDB insert can't return the type I want?

Tags: haskell, rethinkdb

I'm trying to insert a `User` into RethinkDB with my `saveUser` function.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
module User where

import Database.RethinkDB
import Data.Text (Text)
import Data.Aeson (FromJSON, ToJSON)
import GHC.Generics
import Database.RethinkDB

saveUser ::  RethinkDBHandle -> User -> IO User
saveUser handle user = run handle $ table "test" # insert
  ["email" := (email user),
  "hash" := (hash user),
  "institutionId" := (institutionId user)]


getAllUsers :: RethinkDBHandle -> IO [User]
getAllUsers handle = run handle $ table "test"


data User = User {
  id :: Maybe String,
  email :: String,
  hash :: String,
  institutionId :: String
} deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToJSON User
instance FromJSON User
instance ToDatum User
instance FromDatum User
instance Expr User
```

The [run](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rethinkdb-1.15.2.1/docs/Database-RethinkDB.html#v:run) function returns an `IO Result`. From reading the docs, it looks like [`Result`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rethinkdb-1.15.2.1/docs/Database-RethinkDB.html#t:Result) is a [`Datum`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rethinkdb-1.15.2.1/docs/Database-RethinkDB.html#t:Datum), and my `User` is also a `Datum`, so I expect to be able to return an `IO User` from this function, like I return an `IO [User]` in the `getAllUsers` function. However, I get the following error:

```
    No instance for (Result User) arising from a use of ‘run’
    In the expression: run handle
    In the expression:
      run handle
      $ table "test"
        # insert
            ["email" := (email user), "hash" := (hash user),
             "institutionId" := (institutionId user)]
    In an equation for ‘saveUser’:
        saveUser handle user
          = run handle
            $ table "test"
              # insert
                  ["email" := (email user), "hash" := (hash user),
                   "institutionId" := (institutionId user)]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

When I change the type of the `saveUser` function back to `IO Datum`, it works again. How does Haskell infer that my function can't return an `IO User` when `run` returns an `IO Result`?

Comment: `Result` is a class. `Datum` is an *instance* of that class. I'm not familiar with the library, but I would assume that you need an `instance Result User`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, it appears that there is the instance

```
FromDatum a => Result [a]
```

Which explains why your `getAllUsers` function works, however, there is not an instance for

```
FromDatum a => Result a
```

Instead, it appears the author of this API would rather you use the instance

```
FromDatum a => Result (Maybe a)
```

so that you can properly handle failures in case a user was improperly inserted.  If you change your function to

```
saveUser ::  RethinkDBHandle -> User -> IO (Maybe User)
saveUser handle user = run handle $ table "test" # insert
  ["email" := (email user),
  "hash" := (hash user),
  "institutionId" := (institutionId user)]
```

then it should compile just fine.  (I tried installing rethinkdb but apparently my version of `network` conflicts with it)

Comment: Correct. Also see the documentation for `run`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rethinkdb-1.15.2.1/docs/Database-RethinkDB.html#v:run